# Probability that event $A$ occurs before event $B$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Given two events, $A$ and $B$, that will each eventually occur, what's the probability $P_{_{AB}}\ \ $ that $A$ occurs before $B$?  What you're given are the two *pdf*'s $a(t),b(t)$ such that, as usual, they're both $\ge0$ and$\int_{t=0}^\infty\ a(t)dt=1=\int_{t=0}^\infty\ b(t)dt$.

What I'm thinking, but can't seem to prove, is the following. Let $A(t)=\int_{0}^t\ a(t')dt'$ and $B(t)=\int_{0}^t\ b(t')dt'$ be the cumulative probabilities. Then
$$P_{_{AB}}\hspace{10pt} =\int_0^\infty a(t)\left(1-B(t)\right)dt\ = \hspace{5pt}1-P_{_{BA}}$$
Is that right? If so, how's it proved? Or, if not, what is right?

Comment: The probability that "$A$ occurs before $B$" does not make sense. Don't you mean something like the probability of event $A<B$ where $A$ and $B$ are random variables (not events)?

Comment: @drhab $A$ and $B$ are discrete events. But we don't know when they will occur. For example, to be a little macabre, you and I will both die. Who's first? Then the pdf's are like information derived from insurance company actuarial tables.

Comment: Do you mean that $a(t)$ is the pdf of $T_A$, the time of occurrence of $A$, and $b(t)$ is the pdf of $T_B$, the time of occurrence of $B$? If so, then the probability required is $\mathrm{P}(T_A<T_B)$.

Comment: @Yuta $a(t)$ is the usual pdf -- it's the probability that event $A$ will occur in the (infinitesimal) interval $t$ to $t+dt$. And the cumulative probability $A(t)$ is then just the probability that $A$ will have occurred by or before $t$. So $A(\infty)=1$ just means that, with certainty, $A$ eventually occurs. (...I'm really confused about why the problem statement isn't clear.)

Comment: The problem is clear alright, but its formulation is not in accordance with terminology of probability theory (see my first comment, and my answer). Also I have never heard of "discrete events". Btw, I bet I will die first, so don't worry :-).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be found is $P_{AB}:=P\left(X_{B}>X_{A}\right)$ where $X_A,X_B$ denote the waiting times.

Here $X_A$ and $X_B$ are *random variables*, $\{X_{B}>X_{A}\}$ is an *event* (of which we want to find the probability) and $A$ and $B$ are not more than *labels* or *indices* that serve by discerning.

If $X_{A}$ and $X_{B}$ are independent (this is not mentioned in your question) then indeed:

$$\begin{aligned}P_{AB} & =P\left(X_{B}>X_{A}\right)\\
 & =\int_{0}^{\infty}P\left(X_{B}>X_{A}\mid X_{A}=t\right)a\left(t\right)dt\\
 & =\int_{0}^{\infty}P\left(X_{B}>t\mid X_{A}=t\right)a\left(t\right)dt\\
 & =\int_{0}^{\infty}P\left(X_{B}>t\right)a\left(t\right)dt\\
 & =\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(1-B\left(t\right)\right)a\left(t\right)dt
\end{aligned}
$$as you expected.

Here $B$ denotes the CDF of $X_{B}$ and the fourth equality
is based on independence.

This can also be expressed as $1-P_{BA}$ because in this situation
we have $P\left(X_{A}=X_{B}\right)=0$.

This follows from the fact that at least one (that is enough) of the random variables has a PDF.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry if the terminology was nonstandard. Yeah, I should have mentioned A and B are independent. And, yeah, my semi-formal/informal thinking was exactly as illustrated in your second-to-last integral, but without the preceding argument leading up to it.

Comment: You are very welcome.